# Silencing 'siunitx' and 'physics' package \qty warning

Tags: siunitx, warnings, physics, silence

I want to use the `siunitx`and the `physics`package, using the \qty definition of `siunitx`. Following the issued warning

*Package siunitx Warning: Detected the "physics" package: omitting definition of \qty. If you want to use \qty with the siunitx definition, add \AtBeginDocument{\RenewCommandCopy\qty\SI} to your preamble.*

I added the recommended line

`\AtBeginDocument{\RenewCommandCopy\qty\SI}`

right after importing both packages. My problem: The warning still appears. I tried silencing the warning but even in the most brutal way I know

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside,final,openbib,pdftex]{scrbook}
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningsOff*
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{physics}
\AtBeginDocument{\RenewCommandCopy\qty\SI}
\begin{document}
A few chapters and a bib
\end{document}
```

the error still remains. To state the obvious: I only want to eliminate this specific warning in a way like `\WarningFilter{siunitx}{Detected}` but since not even turning off all warnings helped it goes without saying that this version doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Messages from `siunitx` use the `expl3` message system, which `silence` does not know about. However, this system is set up to allow users to control message display, so we can simply redirect the message:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{physics}
\AtBeginDocument{\RenewCommandCopy\qty\SI}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_redirect_name:nnn { siunitx } { physics-pkg } { none }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
A few chapters and a bib
\end{document}
```