# How to insert a character between the number and the unit in the siunitx package

Tags: siunitx

I want the create a compound adjective, e.g.,

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
The $50-\si{\hertz}$ signal is obtained via...
\end{document}
```

The output is horrible, though

[image]

My goal is to get something like

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: `\si` and `\SI` are deprecated. Use `\unit` and `\qty` instead.

Comment: @Mico `\qty` breaks when using along with the physics package.

Comment: Please see the query [Silencing 'siunitx' and 'physics' package \qty warning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/681700/5001) and, in particular, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/681701/5001) for a workaround.

Comment: First time here, otherwise this would be a comment (which it should be) rather than an answer. The issue here is nothing to do with your use of siunitx. You have a hyphen in a maths environment, which outputs a minus sign. Do what you'd do anywhere else $50\text{-}...$. Aside 1: There is no need to use inline maths here. Aside 2: I don't like using hyphens with (SI) units (against SI for one thing), but some publishers allow/insist on it when use is adjectival. If there is an insistence on adjectival hyphen (and siunitx use) here, then 'The 50-Hz signal...' (or 'The 50-\si{\hertz} signal...')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set a non-default value for the `quantity-product` formatting option. (The default value is `\,`, i.e., "thinspace".)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
The \qty[quantity-product={-\kern-1pt}]{50}{\hertz} signal is obtained via \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: ‘Do not do this’: the requirements for units are clear, the symbols are not affected by grammatical rules